# How to check missing values in dataframe for specific datatype?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, dataframe

df1:

```
    Name    marks   class   Avg   is_stud   Date
0   Tom     91.55   classA  45.0    True    10/2/2011
1   Jack    98.66   classB  65.0    False   11/2/2011
2   nick    NaN     classC  NaN     False   12/2/2011
3   juli    90.60   classA  14.0    False   13/2/2016
4   NaN     79.60   classB  58.0    True    10/2/2011
5   ramy    NaN     classC  22.0    False   11/2/2011
6   suzane  85.00   classA  65.0    False   12/2/2015
7   nick    NaN     classB  96.0    False   13/2/2012
8   Tom    69.69    classC  NaN     NaN     NaN
9   NaN    56.20    classD  NaN     NaN     NaN
```

hello all,
i want to find missing value in each column and add other column (mean ,median, mode ) to the output for only numeric (int, float) datatype else it should be null.
if a column has all unique values then mode = median.
if there is no missing value in the data frame then return empty data frame of output.

output :

```
col_name  no.of missing  mean   median   mode
Name               2    Nan     Nan      Nan
marks              3    81.61   85.0     85.0
Avg                3    52.14   58.0     65.0
is_stud            2    Nan     Nan      Nan
Date               2    Nan     Nan      Nan
```

thanks

Comment: `df1.isna().sum()`?

Comment: that will give all columns missing value only

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see, you want to the operation on only `int` and `float` values, I would suggest checking for the type of the column first and then performing the operation.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats

for col in df.columns:
    if (df[col].dtype == 'int64') or (df[col].dtype == 'float64'):
        mean = np.mean(df[col])
        median = np.median(df[col])
        mode = stats.mode(df[col])
        print('Mean', mean, '\nMedian', median, '\Mode', mode, '\for column', col)
```

Once you get these values, you could print them in the way that's been shown in your question using `pd.DataFrame`